# My Dynamic Array template class is doing weird things

Tags: c++, string, class, templates, memory

[The code](http://pastebin.com/NpdYgj7L)

I'm having a problem with it handling strings. Whenever I try a string, I get a lovely little error code:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77e815de in arraytest.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0xabababab.
```

It handles int, double, and char just fine. I also tried the exact same test string I was using (the alphabet) as a char* and it did that fine too. It just pukes on strings, for a reason that I cannot quite fathom. I really don't know where to go with it next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO, a couple pointers: 1) Post all relevant code within your question, external links to code dumps are frowned upon. 2) Please read [sscee.org](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with your reallocation code in `push_back`

```
template<class type>
void DynamicArray<type>::push_back(type newValue)
{
        ++_size;   // <=== **

        if (_size > _capacity) // If size larger than capacity
        {
                _capacity *= CAPACITY_MULT; // double capacity
                type* tempArray = new type[_capacity];// Create temporary array with new capacity
                // Copy array values into temporary array

                for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)    // <=== **
                {
                        tempArray[i] = dynArray[i];
                }
                // Delete dynArray
                delete[] dynArray;
                // Insert new value at end of temporary array
                // Set dynArray to temporary array
                dynArray = tempArray;
        }

        dynArray[_size - 1] = newValue;
}
```

You start by increasing the size of the current container *before* checking if there is room for the new element. Then you use the new size when copying the old values to a new array.

This might seem to work for primitive types, but a `std::string` will try to copy its own internal data (which isn't there) and liklely cause an access violation.